# Unable to add ACE to SACl of Kernel Object using SetKernelObjectSecurity

Tags: windows, security, acl

Edit 1

Here file handle I am using is a DLL file from the system32 directory.

I tried following things too:

1. Using `LABEL_SECURITY_INFORMATION` instead of `SACL_SECURITY_INFORMATION`
2. I tried using `hr = SetSecurityInfo(hFile, SE_KERNEL_OBJECT, LABEL_SECURITY_INFORMATION, NULL, NULL, NULL, pNewSACL);` to set SACl instead of `SetSecurityDescriptorSacl` and `SetKernelObjectSecurity`

---

original

I am trying to add Audit ACE  to a kernel security object and remove all existing ACE. So I was able to come up with the following code by referring to documentation and other posts on the internet. Finally, I am able to run SetKernelObjectSecurity without error but when I again try to validate if the ACE is added then I see ACE Count to be 0. As of right now, I am stuck at this point. It will be great if someone can help me with how to properly change ACE in Kernel Object SACl.

Thank you.

Here is a brief overview of the code:

- You can see that there are 5 Sections
- SECTION 1: Create handle
- SECTION 2: Get Kernel object security and pOldSacl
- SECTION 3: Create newSACL from oldSACL
- SECTION 4: Add newSACL to kernel object security
- SECTION 5: Validate if SACL is updated
- Aside from this there are 5 `// NOTE` tags which shows value of ace count at various points

Code is as follows:

```
void setAceAudit()
{
    DWORD dwRes = 0;
    PACL pOldSACL = NULL, pNewSACL = NULL;
    PSECURITY_DESCRIPTOR pSS = NULL;
    EXPLICIT_ACCESS ea;

    HANDLE  hFile = NULL;

// SECTION 1: Create handle

    hFile = CreateFile2(filePath,
        FILE_GENERIC_EXECUTE | FILE_GENERIC_READ | FILE_GENERIC_WRITE | READ_CONTROL | WRITE_OWNER | ACCESS_SYSTEM_SECURITY,
        FILE_SHARE_READ | FILE_SHARE_WRITE | FILE_SHARE_DELETE,
        OPEN_EXISTING,
        nullptr);

    if (hFile == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE && GetLastError() == ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED)
    {
        // A directory will fail without FILE_FLAG_BACKUP_SEMANTICS.
        CREATEFILE2_EXTENDED_PARAMETERS extendedParams = {
            sizeof(CREATEFILE2_EXTENDED_PARAMETERS),
            FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL,
            FILE_FLAG_BACKUP_SEMANTICS,
            0,
            nullptr,
            nullptr
        };
        hFile = CreateFile2(filePath,
            FILE_GENERIC_EXECUTE | FILE_GENERIC_READ | FILE_GENERIC_WRITE | READ_CONTROL | WRITE_OWNER | ACCESS_SYSTEM_SECURITY,
            FILE_SHARE_READ | FILE_SHARE_WRITE | FILE_SHARE_DELETE,
            OPEN_EXISTING,
            &extendedParams);
    }

// SECTION 1: End
// SECTION 2: Get Kernel object security and pOldSacl

    DWORD                dwSize = 0;
    HRESULT hr = S_OK;
    if (!GetKernelObjectSecurity(hFile, LABEL_SECURITY_INFORMATION, pSS, dwSize, &dwSize))
    {
        DWORD dwError = GetLastError();

        if (ERROR_INSUFFICIENT_BUFFER != dwError)
        {
            hr = HRESULT_FROM_WIN32(dwError);
        }
        else if (NULL == (pSS = (PSECURITY_DESCRIPTOR)LocalAlloc(LPTR, dwSize)))
        {
            hr = E_OUTOFMEMORY;
        }
        else if (!GetKernelObjectSecurity(hFile, LABEL_SECURITY_INFORMATION, pSS, dwSize, &dwSize))
        {
            hr = HRESULT_FROM_WIN32(GetLastError());
        }
    }
    else
    {
        hr = E_UNEXPECTED;
    }

    VERIFY_ARE_EQUAL(hr, S_OK);

    
    BOOL bSaclPresent = FALSE;
    BOOL bSaclDefaulted = FALSE;

    if (!GetSecurityDescriptorSacl(pSS, &bSaclPresent, &pOldSACL, &bSaclDefaulted))
    {
        hr = HRESULT_FROM_WIN32(GetLastError());
    }

// SECTION 2: End
// SECTION 3: Create newSACL from oldSACL

    ZeroMemory(&ea, sizeof(EXPLICIT_ACCESS));
    ea.grfAccessPermissions = 0X11000000;
    ea.grfAccessMode = SET_AUDIT_SUCCESS;
    ea.grfInheritance = NO_PROPAGATE_INHERIT_ACE;
    ea.Trustee.TrusteeForm = TRUSTEE_IS_NAME;
    ea.Trustee.ptstrName = L"Administrator";

    dwRes = SetEntriesInAcl(1, &ea, pOldSACL, &pNewSACL);
    if (ERROR_SUCCESS != dwRes) {
        LOG_OUTPUT(L"SetEntriesInAcl Error %lu %ld\n", dwRes, GetLastError());
        return dwRes;
    }

    for (int ii = pNewSACL->AceCount - 1; ii >= 0; ii--)
    {
        PSYSTEM_MANDATORY_LABEL_ACE pAce = NULL; // Only access pAce->Header until checking AceType

        if (!GetAce(pNewSACL, ii, (LPVOID*)&pAce))
        {
            VERIFY_ARE_EQUAL((DWORD)0, GetLastError());
        }
        DeleteAce(pNewSACL, ii);
    }

    PSID    pIntegritySid = NULL;

    BOOL    fRet;

    if (true)
    {
        fRet = ConvertStringSidToSidW(SDDL_ML_HIGH, &pIntegritySid);
    }
    else
    {
        fRet = ConvertStringSidToSidW(SDDL_ML_MEDIUM, &pIntegritySid);
    }

    VERIFY_IS_TRUE(fRet);

    fRet = AddAuditAccessAce(pNewSACL, ACL_REVISION_DS, OBJECT_INHERIT_ACE | CONTAINER_INHERIT_ACE, pIntegritySid, FALSE, FALSE);

    VERIFY_IS_TRUE(fRet);

    DWORD absSize = 0;
    DWORD daclSize = 0;
    DWORD saclSize = 0;
    DWORD ownerSize = 0;
    DWORD primGroupSize = 0;
    fRet = MakeAbsoluteSD(pSS, NULL, &absSize, NULL, &daclSize, NULL, &saclSize, NULL, &ownerSize, NULL, &primGroupSize);

    PSECURITY_DESCRIPTOR pSD = LocalAlloc(0, absSize);
    fRet = MakeAbsoluteSD(pSS,
        pSD, &absSize,
        /*pSD->Dacl =*/ (PACL)LocalAlloc(0, daclSize), &daclSize,
        /*pSD->Sacl =*/ (PACL)LocalAlloc(0, saclSize), &saclSize,
        /*pSD->Owner =*/ (PSID)LocalAlloc(0, ownerSize), &ownerSize,
        /*pSD->Group =*/ (PSID)LocalAlloc(0, primGroupSize), &primGroupSize);

// NOTE 1: Verified that ACE count is 1 in pNewSACL before inserting it
// SECTION 3: End
// SECTION 4: Add newSACL to kernel object security

    if (!SetSecurityDescriptorSacl(pSD, TRUE, pNewSACL, FALSE))
    {
        DWORD dwError = GetLastError();
        hr = HRESULT_FROM_WIN32(dwError);
    }

// NOTE 2: Verified that new SACL in pSD has ACE count as 1 by using GetSecurityDescriptorSacl

    if (!SetKernelObjectSecurity(hFile, SACL_SECURITY_INFORMATION, pSD))
    {
        // NOTE 3: Call flow doesn't go here so SetKernelObjectSecurity is success.
        DWORD dwError = GetLastError();
        hr = HRESULT_FROM_WIN32(dwError);
    }

// SECTION 4: End
// SECTION 5: Validate if SACL is updated

// NOTE 4: Following code is to validate that ACE count is changed by using GetKernelObjectSecurity and GetSecurityDescriptorSacl but as in (NOTE 5) it is found to be 0

    dwSize = 0;
    PSECURITY_DESCRIPTOR pSD1 = NULL;

    if (!GetKernelObjectSecurity(hFile, LABEL_SECURITY_INFORMATION, pSD1, dwSize, &dwSize))
    {
        DWORD dwError = GetLastError();

        if (ERROR_INSUFFICIENT_BUFFER != dwError)
        {
            hr = HRESULT_FROM_WIN32(dwError);
        }
        else if (NULL == (pSD1 = (PSECURITY_DESCRIPTOR)LocalAlloc(LPTR, dwSize)))
        {
            hr = E_OUTOFMEMORY;
        }
        else if (!GetKernelObjectSecurity(hFile, LABEL_SECURITY_INFORMATION, pSD1, dwSize, &dwSize))
        {
            hr = HRESULT_FROM_WIN32(GetLastError());
        }
    }
    else
    {
        // Should never get here, as dwSize was initialized to 0,
        // so the call to GetKernelObjectSecurity should fail.
        // Adding this to avoid Prefast/Prefix complaining that
        // potential use of NULL pSD below.
        hr = E_UNEXPECTED;
    }

    VERIFY_ARE_EQUAL(hr, S_OK);

    PACL pSacl = NULL;
    bSaclPresent = FALSE;
    bSaclDefaulted = FALSE;

    if (!GetSecurityDescriptorSacl(pSD1, &bSaclPresent, &pSacl, &bSaclDefaulted))
    {
        hr = HRESULT_FROM_WIN32(GetLastError());
    }

    VERIFY_ARE_EQUAL(hr, S_OK);
    VERIFY_ARE_NOT_EQUAL(pSacl, (PACL)NULL);
    VERIFY_ARE_EQUAL(bSaclPresent, (BOOL)true);
    VERIFY_ARE_NOT_EQUAL(pSacl->AceCount, (WORD)0); // NOTE 5: ACE Count is 0

// SECTION 5: End

    CloseHandle(hFile);

}
```

Comment: I just replaced `LABEL_SECURITY_INFORMATION` with `SACL_SECURITY_INFORMATION` and it seems to do what you want.

Comment: @Luke Thank you for the response. I tried it but it didn't work. Is it possible for you to share the code that you are working with?

Comment: https://pastecode.io/s/yw9m09vp

Comment: @Luke thanks for answering the question problem was label and permissions, it will be great if you can write an answer so I can give bounty. Now code works for AddAuditAceType but when I replace that line with `AddMandatoryAce(pNewSACL, ACL_REVISION_DS, OBJECT_INHERIT_ACE | CONTAINER_INHERIT_ACE, NULL, pIntegritySid);` I get pSacl in verification step as null. After trial and error, I found that here I need LABEL_SECURITY_INFORMATION. As per https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/secauthz/security-information, SACL_SECURITY_INFORMATION is for SACL then why do I need other flag?

Comment: @Luke Bounty is going to be wasted if I don't offer it. Please write an answer so that I can offer it.

Comment: `SACL_SECURITY_INFORMATION` is required to access the SACL and `LABEL_SECURITY_INFORMATION` is required to access the mandatory integrity label ACE in the SACL. Obviously you can't access the label ACE in the SACL without also being able to access the SACL, so you'll need both flags in that case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace `LABEL_SECURITY_INFORMATION` with `SACL_SECURITY_INFORMATION`.